# ListView Listener

Tags: java, listview, javafx, listener

I have some code below.

```
public class TodoItem {
    private String description;
    private String details;
    private LocalDate deadline;

    public TodoItem(String description, String details, LocalDate deadline) {
        this.description = description;
        this.details = details;
        this.deadline = deadline;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getDetails() {
        return details;
    }

    public void setDetails(String details) {
        this.details = details;
    }

    public LocalDate getDeadline() {
        return deadline;
    }
}
```

```
public class Controller {
    @FXML
    private ListView<TodoItem> todoListView;
    @FXML
    private TextArea todoDetails;
    @FXML
    private Label todoDeadLine;
    private List<TodoItem> todoItems;


    public void initialize() {
        todoListView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<TodoItem>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends TodoItem> observable, TodoItem oldValue, TodoItem newValue) {
                if(newValue != null) {
                    TodoItem item = todoListView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
                    todoDetails.setText(item.getDetails());
                    DateTimeFormatter df = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM d, yyyy"); // "d M yy");
                    todoDeadLine.setText(df.format(item.getDeadline()));
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The program is fine but when I tried to play with the code by writing this line `TodoItem item = todoListView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();` outside of the listener (I commented out the whole todoListView.getSelectionModel().... part) and I got a null value. So my question is, Do I need to write `TodoItem item = todoListView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();` inside the listener to able to get the data?

Thanks.

Comment: Ultimately, it's a question of when you want the code to be invoked. If you try to get the selected item directly inside the `initialize` method, then you're very likely to get `null` as a result. The `initialize` method is invoked during the process of loading the FXML file, after the FXML-injected fields have been injected, but before loading has complete (basically, it's the last thing that happens). But that also means it's highly unlikely your `ListView` has been added to a `Scene` yet, let alone being displayed. The user could not have selected an item before the list is displayed.

Comment: Your listener is invoked when the user changes the selection. That's why getting the selected item in the listener worked (though you don't handle the case where the user clears the selection). But you could have used other approaches (e.g., maybe you want the user to press a button to display the details, thus you would put the get-selected-item code in the button's on-action handler). Also, note that, in your code, `todoListView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem()` is returning the same object that `newValue` references (i.e., you could just do `todoDetails.setText(newValue.getDetails())`)

Comment: Nothing is selected in the `ListView` at this point. Try things in the following order. 1. Set `ListView` with data. 2. do `todoListView.getSelectionModel().select(0);`. 3. Try `TodoItem item = todoListView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
                    todoDetails.setText(item.getDetails());`. I haven't tested this, so I don't know if it will work, but the flow of things seems right.

Comment: @Slaw, Thanks for your comments. "Your listener is invoked when the user changes the selection". It is clear now.

Comment: @SedJ601, I works. I manually set ListView with data in initialize() and yes it returns the some data. Thanks for your comments.